# Is it possible to set Tekton PipelineRun history in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, redhat, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am currently seeing only the last 5 pipeline runs in openshift. As I am not an administrator of openshift at my company I dont have insight if this was configured or not and could not find an answer googling this.

So here my questions go:

- Can I configure Tekton to e.g. keep the history of the last 30 Runs?
- If yes, how would I approach this using the OpenShift Operator?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With Tekton Operator, you can configure the [pruner](https://tekton.dev/docs/operator/tektonconfig/#pruner) to keep the amount of resources you want.
In the TektonConfig you can specify the total amount of resources to keep:

```
pruner:
  resources:
    - taskrun
    - pipelinerun
  keep: 100
  schedule: "* * * * *"
```